# Implement a routing protocol in omnet

Tags: c++, routes, omnet++, inet, veins

I am a newbie in Omnet++/inet and trying to write a simple routing algorithm (using C++) and implement it in my Omnet++ Project.

any idea on what is the best practice on how to get start with this?
any simple examples that can help me would be appreciated.
I am using Omnet++ 5.0  , inet 3.4 on Ubuntu 14.4

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what kind of routing you want to implement. If you just generally interested in routing (i.e. not particularly in IPv4 or 6 routing algorithms) then I would recommend to use only OMNeT++ (without INET). Start with the tic-toc turorial in OMNeT++ which already has a very simple routing (random direction) in a later step. You can refine that algorithm to fit your needs.

Comment: actually, i want to implement an adhoc routing algorithm based on a calculated metric for vanet  so i has been thinking  of implementing it first using inet and try to implement it using veins.....